# React Native: How to Display Components at the Start and End of the Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

**Problem:** I have 2 Functional Components component1,component2 and 1 FlatList having its own RenderComponent.
When I merge this 3 Components(Comp1, Comp2 & Flatlist) under one View I get output as seen in image 1. I expect an output as Image 2. How can this be achieved and Is this possible.

**Image 1** (Output I am getting)

[image]

**Image 2** (Expected Output)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add your 1st component explicitly at the first index of your Flatlist, 2nd component at the last index, and traverse the list additionally two more times.

E.g: If the length of `data` is 10 then you should consider the length 12 so this would work

```
// consider this is the data to show in flalist
const data = [{...}, {...}, {...}];

// Add single dummy item to the beginning of an array
data.unshift({...});

// Add single dummy item to the end of an array
data.push({...});

<FlatList
    columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}
    data={data}
    numColumns={2}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
     // first item
     if (index === 0) {
      return <ComponentOne />
     }
     // last item
     if (index === data.length - 1) {
      return <ComponentTwo />
     }
     return <Item />
   }}
/>
```

Comment: Hey ! Thank You this surely worked :-) I just have one question it is the only optimal way to do this ?